# How to get specfic data of row as dictionary by search in coredata

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swift4.2

i had added this code for search via product_id in coredata but that returns all records i want to just get specific data from row that contain that product_id

```
    let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "CartEntity")
        let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "product_id == %@", "\(Product_id)")
        request.predicate = predicate
        request.fetchLimit = 1

        do{
            let count = try managedContext.count(for: request)
            if(count == 0){
            // no matching object
                print("no")
                self.savecoredata()
            }
            else{
                let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "CartEntity")
                       request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
                       do {
                           let result = try managedContext.fetch(request)
                           for dataresult in result as! [NSManagedObject] {
                               let userName = dataresult.value(forKey: "proname") as! String
                               let age = dataresult.value(forKey: "price") as! String
                               print("User Name is : "+userName+" and price is : "+age)
                            print(datastored)
                           }
                       } catch {
                           print("Fetching data Failed")
                       }
                print("yes")
//                deleteFeed(id: "\(Product_id)")
                // first delete old and than insert new id
            }
          }
        catch let error as NSError {
             print("Could not fetch \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
          }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have to different requests, first you use one *with* a predicate and then you use one without a predicate which will return all rows. Either reuse the predicate for the second request as well or even better skip the first `count` request that seems unnecessary and perform only the second one

```
let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "CartEntity")
request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "product_id == %@", "\(Product_id)")
do {
    let result = try managedContext.fetch(request)
    for dataresult in result as! [NSManagedObject] {
//... rest of code
```

Comment: This small block of code solved my problem and saved my whole day

Answer (score 0):

First of all use the predicate of the first request and secondly use a specific fetch request to return the actual `NSManagedObject` subclass. The benefit is to get the values directly with dot notation rather than with error-prone KVC (key-value coding).

This is the corresponding logic of your entire code, however the `savecoredata` line seems to be pointless

```
let request : NSFetchRequest<CartEntity> = CartEntity.fetchRequest()
request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "product_id == %ld", Product_id)

do {
   if let result = try managedContext.fetch(request).first {
       let userName = result.proname
       let price = result.price
       print("User Name is : \(userName) and price is : \(price)")
   } else {
       // no matching object
       print("no")
       self.savecoredata()
   }
} catch {
   print(error)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be with your predicate. Check if the `product_id` is string or integer. If you are doing casting then apply format `"%d", "%ld"`

```
let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "CartEntity")
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "product_id = \(Product_id)")
request.predicate = predicate
request.fetchLimit = 1
var count = 0
do{
    count = try managedContext.count(for: request)
}
catch let error {
    print("Could not fetch \(error), \(error.localizedDescription)")
}

guard count != 0 else {
    // no matching object
    print("no")
    self.savecoredata()
    return
}

// remove predicate, which is actually not required.
request.predicate = nil

request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
do {
    let result = try managedContext.fetch(request)
    for dataresult in result as! [NSManagedObject] {
        let userName = dataresult.value(forKey: "proname") as! String
        let age = dataresult.value(forKey: "price") as! String
        print("User Name is : "+userName+" and price is : "+age)
        print(datastored)
    }
} catch let error {
    print("Fetching data Failed - \(error)")
}
print("yes")
// deleteFeed(id: "\(Product_id)")
// first delete old and than insert new id
```